# How can i assing ip_local_port_range for different network interfaces

Tags: port, interface

I want to ask is it possible to specify different port ranges (ip_local_port_range) for different physical interfaces on the same PC. Or is it the same for all physical interfaces.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as this "ip variable" applies system wide. And to my understanding, a [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29) is associated with ip address and not with physical interface.

> ip_local_port_range - 2 INTEGERS
>
> Defines the local port range that is used by TCP and UDP to   choose
>   the local port. The first number is the first, the second the last
>   local port number.
>   If possible, it is better these numbers have
>   different parity.     (one even and one odd values)   The default values
>   are 32768 and 60999 respectively.

Ref: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

Comment: Every, physical interface have IP addres assigned, with it's own port ranges i guess. So if i set ip_local_port_range it applies for port ranges for both physical interfaces.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you saying. But anyway, to repeat what I have said, it is not possible to set port range for different interfaces (with or without ip address). And your guess is also not correct "Every, physical interface have IP addres assigned, with it's own port ranges i guess". Interfaces have no "port range defined" by default. I suggest you take your time to understand what port is, and their relation with system. If you are actually looking for a way to "bind" a service to a particular interface, then that's another thing.